# How can include the component view in plugins

Tags: plugin, view, custom-component

I have custom component and plugins and listing some details in table after click on the table i'll go to details page. i want show the one of details in article, so i created a custom plugins and got the id of the details, but i dont know how to call the details view in plugins.

Answer (score 6):

From joomla 3.0 onwards a layout sharing feature is introduced, using it you can call a layout across views or extensions. It requires creating a layout object and then render the view using that object as:

```
$layout = new JLayoutFile('my_layout', $basePath = JPATH_ROOT .'/components/com_something/layouts');
$html = $layout->render();
```

this will render the 'my_layout.php' layout file found in JPATH_ROOT .'/components/com_something/layouts' directory. So you can try the above code in your plugin to call your component view if you are using joomla 3.0+

For more details check this page :- https://docs.joomla.org/Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout

Comment: Thk it working. one more thing if possible to view product details virtuemart  like this ?

Comment: I don't use Virtuemart, but if it follows Joomla's standard then you can override its default layout to supports JLayout. Here are some useful articles: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core and https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides